# Can't display linklabel text in a datagridviewlinkcolumn

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a little but pretty annoying problem:

I have created a datagridview and bound it to a datasource. 
Then now I want to add a column which will display links for the user to click. 
In order to do that i added a datagridviewlinkcolumn. For each rows of the datagrid I set the value of the cell in that column to the text i want to be displayed. But it shows nothing. All the datagridlinkcolumn is filled with "blank text".

Here is my code:

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvColDeletion = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
dgvColDeletion.Name = "Deletion";
dgvColDeletion.HeaderText = "";
dgvColDeletion.ReadOnly = false;
dgvTrainings.Columns.Add(dgvColDeletion);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTrainings.Rows)
{
     row.Cells["Deletion"].Value = "Delete";
}
dgvColDeletion.Update();
dgvTrainings.Update();
```

I also tried with setting directly linklabels or datagridviwlinkcells, but the problem still remains.

I cant get any clue why this isn't working.

Any help will be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To display the same link text for every cell, set the `UseColumnTextForLinkValue` property to true and set the `Text` property to the desired link text.

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvColDeletion = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
dgvColDeletion.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
dgvColDeletion.Text = "Delete";
```

Comment: It worked here, thank you! But, how can I handle the clicked link?

Comment: I solved it. Clicking on link will trigger CellContentClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope this will helps to you.

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvColDeletion = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();  


dgvColDeletion.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.Text = "Delete";<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.ActiveLinkColor = Color.White;<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.LinkColor = Color.Blue;<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.TrackVisitedState = true;<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.VisitedLinkColor = Color.YellowGreen;<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.Name = "Delete";<br/>
                dgvColDeletion.HeaderText = "Delete";<br/>
                if (grid_shared.Columns.Contains("Delete") == false)<br/>
                {<br/>
                    dgvColDeletion.Columns.Add(lnkDelete);<br/>
                    dgvColDeletion.Columns["Delete"].Width = 40;<br/>
                }<br/>
```

Happy coding..:)